# can i make my android application to login through facebook, linked in, twitter and google plus?

Tags: java, android

i am facing problem in to import google_play_service_lib, which is making conflict with twitter and linkedIn lib

mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(getActivity(), this, this)
        .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
                "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity").build();`

Comment: PLease can you explain wich type of conflict have you encounter? there is some logcat informations?

Comment: some time support libray conflicts...keep same version of jar in every project you are linking as library

Comment: actually when i import google_play_service_lib and add it through buildPath the Twitter and linkedIn imports shows error......

Comment: import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;